# Generate constant voltage sources from the power supply using MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, analog, chip-design

Suppose if I have a Vdd of 1.4V and I want to generate 1.2V and 1V constant voltages even when there are slight changes in the load values, is there any possible way of achieving this?
Well I tried doing this by using current mirrors and resistance ladders, but I couldn't achieve constant voltages from it because the load was changing. Can any modification be made to these methods or is there any solution for this?

Edit 1 :

This question has been asked in the perspective of IC Designing where I'm trying to lower the power dissipation my designed circuit by giving lower supply voltages to some of the components. Now the only way I can do this is if I can generate these voltages from Vdd considering I want only only one power pin in the IC.

Edit 2(3) :

The value of the current taken by the vdd is in the range of mA and the one needed for the 1V is around 80uA

Comment: Is this for an IC design you're doing or are you looking for a discrete/board-level solution? And how much current are we talking about?

Comment: Because I don't know of any regulators that would work "irrespective of the load", e.g. on 0.00000000001ohms load.

Comment: yeah I'm talking in the context related to IC Designing only.

Comment: Resistor divider followed by op-amp. As others have said, this will work TO A POINT. There is no such thing as "irrespective of load." For stability, external capacitor may be required. (I don't design IC's, but I see that mixed signal processors occasionally require an external capacitor on an internal reference voltage).

Comment: @RespawnedFluff, I guess the edit has clarified the question.

Comment: @mkeith , Yeah I looked into the possibility of using an opamp but designing an opamp at the transistor level would mean adding a lot of new transistors and this would actually inturn increase the power dissipation.
If there is any other idea with far lesser number of gates would be a better bet.

Comment: How much current is actually needed at 1.2 and 1.0? You need maybe 6 transistors for each voltage. If the current is low, you don't need a fancy output stage. You might be able to bias the op-amp at, say, 1 uA (I don't know because I don't design IC's). If you are designing an IC, I wouldn't think a dozen or so transistors is a big deal. But what do I know? How much current can you save by going to internal split rails?

Comment: Well the current for one of it is around 100uA

Comment: @mkeith, I'm also not an IC designer, but getting 1.2 V output from a 1.4 V Vdd might need more than the simplest op-amp. Just designing an op-amp with only 1.4 V Vdd is not a straightforward task (Or anyway it wasn't in the 90's when I was in school. I'm sure there's lots of well-known designs nowadays).

Comment: @vineel13: please add this info (rough current value to question itself); we don't need a precise figure, but 100uA is probably way less than most readers here (unfamiliar with IC desing) would image you needed.

Comment: You could also look at [this thesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.560.9469&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which claims to survey all known on-chip VRM solutions.

Comment: @ThePhoton, you may be right. On the other hand, the OP is already working in a CMOS process which apparently supports internal VDD of 1V. That implies very low threshold voltage transistors are available. And not much current is needed.

Comment: @vineel13, how much current can you save by lowering the voltage from 1.4? Whatever regulator solution you use will need to have a quiescent current smaller than the savings.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you somehow manage to integrate an inductor inside your chip so that a buck regulator can be realized, using any form of linear regulator to step down a voltage to a lower level is NOT going to "consume" less power (watts) for the same current drawn.

Linear regulators work by just burning-off the excess voltage as heat so there's no net power saving. Of course, if lowering the voltage also lowers the current then this does give a saving but, at the 100 uA level I think you'll be wasting your time and I would recommend trying to figure ways to make your basic circuits take less current.

That is my advice.

Comment: Well actually when I simulated the circuit by giving different voltages the total circuits power consumption did fall down.
And now since I cannot give 3 power pins to my IC I was thinking if I'll be able to generate these voltages from the Vdd itself. 
Well I don't actually remember the exact current values, but I'll look up at these values.

Comment: A switched capacitor converter is another possibility, and probably more realistic for an integrated circuit. No idea if it can be done with reasonable engineering trade-offs.

Comment: Maybe try "losing" some voltage with a low-volt-drop schottkey diode?

Comment: I was thinking that the 1.2 and 1.0 V circuits would consume less current at lower voltages. Meaning that lowering the voltage, even with a linear regulator scheme of some sort, would provide savings. But I don't know what the OP is thinking. If the the circuitry running on 1.2 and 1.0 has a constant current characteristic, then the whole scheme is doomed.